# How to fix javapns.communication.exceptions.InvalidCertificateChainException: Invalid certificate chain

Tags: apple-push-notifications, javapns

I'm new to javapns. I got the below exception when tried to access the code. I checked my certificate it's correct only. I don't know why i'm getting this error.

```
Validating keystore reference: VALID  (keystore was found)
Verifying keystore content: VERIFIED  (no common mistakes detected)
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (javapns.notification.Payload).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
All notifications failed (1):
[1] not transmitted to token b74be..4c4ec javapns.communication.exceptions.InvalidCertificateChainException: Invalid certificate chain (Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown)!  Verify that the keystore you provided was produced according to specs...
```

Comment: It tells you why on the very last line. Search for that on Google

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem and resolved it by changing JVM from OpenJDK 1.7 to OpenJDK 1.6